# Why seperate method works faster than same code inline

Tags: java, methods, coding-style, inline-code

For example searching max in big array. The code with loop in separate method works faster than the same inline code in main. Here running 10 times to get avg time consumed:

```
  Max generated: 999999
  Max is 999999  Time consumed main: 1.8210982999999998 ms
  Max is 999999 Time consumed method: 0.6809502000000001 ms
```

Can someone please explain why such a difference? Thanks.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    private static int[] data = new int[1000000];
    private final static int COUNT = 10;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initData(data);
        long consumedTime;
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int max = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < COUNT; x++) {
            max  = data[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                if (data[i] > max) {
                    max = data[i];
                }
            }
        }
        consumedTime =(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        System.out.println("Max is "+max+ "  Time consumed main: " + (double) (consumedTime)/1000000/COUNT + " ms");


        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for (int x = 0; x < COUNT; x++) {
            max = getMaxOnPart();
        }
        consumedTime=(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        System.out.println("Max is "+max+" Time consumed method: " + (double) (consumedTime)/1000000/COUNT + " ms");
    }

    private static void initData(int[] data) {
        final Random random = new Random();
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            data[i] = random.nextInt(1000000);
            if (max < data[i]) {
                max = data[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("  Max generated: " + max);
    }

    private static int getMaxOnPart() {
        int max = data[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] > max) {
                max = data[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't measuring correctly / consistently. In the first loop

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
```

Is taken outside the 10 repeat loop, thus

```
consumedTime+=(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
```

Measures `1x + 2x + 3x + ...` which will overstate the results by a factor of 55 (if my maths is correct).

Whereas the second called function measurement resets the `startTime` inside the repeat x 10 loop:

```
 startTime = System.nanoTime();
 max = getMaxOnPart();
 consumedTime+=(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
```

Which will sum just the times taken in the method.

Comment: Actually I fixed his problem and the method is still quite a bit faster I'll post an answer so you can see the new code.

Comment: Changed original post due to starttime measuring errors for the first loop. The second looks good enough. It 10 times adds time consumed, like a first one.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have some bugs in your code, but those are just the immediate problem. I'll outline the larger picture of why you won't measure anything very useful here.

A precise answer as to the actual reasons behind a certain performance profile is attainable only by a very detailed and painstaking analysis of the execution of your code. Why? Because it depends on a potentially huge number of factors impinging on the complex function of JVM's just-in-time compiler.

However, this much is certain: you won't be enlightened by the answer because it will not relate much to your code; rather it will relate to *exactly how you have chosen to test it*.

Just to get a feel of the kind of answer you may expect: the level of granularity for most optimizations is the *method*, and a method will be JIT-compiled only after it has been proven to be a hot spot (by default, it will have to accumulate 10,000 invocations). So when you extract the code to a method, you will receive the benefit of compilation as soon as it is performed.

However, there is also the technique of *on-stack replacement*, where a method is optimized while being executed. This is what you have to rely on in the inlined case. The optimizer will detect a hot loop in the middle of the method and compile. This is a very different mechanism, however, so you can expect different results.